# Using Windows Authentication with Connection string in IIS to connect to SQL 2008 R2

Tags: c#, iis-7, connection-string

I'm am making a model first website using MVC4 on IIS7.

Currently my connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="VaultEntities"  
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.VaultDB.csdl|res://*/Models.VaultDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.VaultDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
         provider connection string=&quot;
         data source=sqlserver\instance;
         initial catalog=vault;
         integrated security=True;
         multipleactiveresultsets=True;
         App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The connection was auto generated by Visual Studio 2011 when I added the database through the Model First approach. The query works perfectly locally on my development machine. But it dosen't work on the IIS server.

My guess is that this is because my user account on my development machine has access to the SQL server and when IIS tries to access the SQL server its user account gets denied.

In a perfect world I would add a user on the SQL server and use

```
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

in my connection string, unfortunately I don't have that option.

Without going into details the dba's are...difficult...to work with.

So is there any way to use my AD account in the connection string to login to the SQL server... Or can I make IIS identify itself as me?

Comment: Yes, you could change the Application Pool Identity, which is running the website, to your account in IIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way to use my AD account in the connection string to
>   login to the SQL server... Or can I make IIS identify itself as me?

You can get the application pool to use any AD user you want.

I would not recommend using your own username though. How many times have you locked your username in the last 12 months, and what happens when you leave?

Create/use a service AD account, map it in the application pool, and get the DBAs to give DB access to that user, using trusted connection. Sorry, you'll have to talk to the DBAs! :-)

Comment: Solved by selecting the application pool and clicking on Advanced Settings in the right "Action" panel. Once there I edited the "Identity" to be same as my AD account. Has been working great for 30 minutes or so ;)

Comment: Glad you've got it working! Hopefully you can improve it later. And hopefully you get some nicer DBAs! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there is two options.
1. Either you change you application pool identity to one which has AD access to database, this can be done also by using `impersonation` section in web.config file of your website(Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)).
2. Either you add sql account to your connection string. As I can see you are using EF connection string, it's a little bit different from standard sql connection string. But still has the same part with sql credentials, just replace `integrated security = true` to `used id =...;password=...`. That's all.

Hope this helps.